# ccTouchesBegan is not working in cocos2d-android

Tags: cocos2d-android

I enabled `setIsTouchEnabled(true);` but i cant able to detect the touch begin and touch end in cocos2d-android.

my gamelayer is

```
 public class GameLayer extends CCColorLayer
 {
   protected CCLabel _label;

   public static CCScene scene()
   {
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    GameLayer layer = new GameLayer(ccColor4B.ccc4(90, 90, 255, 255));
    layer.getLabel();

    scene.addChild(layer);
    return scene;

}

public CCLabel getLabel()
{
    return _label;

}

protected GameLayer(ccColor4B color)
{
    super(color);
    this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
    Context context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
    _label = CCLabel.makeLabel("Tap On Me to START the game", "DroidSans", 32);
    _label.setColor(ccColor3B.ccBLACK);
    _label.setPosition(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    addChild(_label);

}

@Override
public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event)
{

    CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(_label.getPosition().x,_label.getPosition().y, _label.getContentSize().width,_label.getContentSize().height);
    CGPoint touchLocation = CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY());
    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(event.getX(), event.getY(), 20, 20);
    System.out.print(":touch Points are - :"+projectileRect+" _  -  _ "+touchLocation+" _  -  _ "+targetRect);
    if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
    {
        System.err.print(": This is intersect function from App :");
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event)
{
    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    CGPoint location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(50, 200));
    System.out.printf("Got touch ", location);
    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();

    return true;

}
 }
```

could any one figure me where i am going wrong? I am not getting any errors and no logs traced in logcat

Comment: Log.e("AM",""+touchLocation); put this code after the CGPoint and check out whether you are getting  the value of the touch or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, just use `System.out.println()` function to output text to console instead of `System.out.printf(), System.err.print()`. When I have replaced them, text has appeared in console.

This:

```
System.out.print(":touch Points are - :"+projectileRect+" _  -  _ "+touchLocation+" _  -  _ "+targetRect);
```

change to:

```
System.out.println(":touch Points are - :"+projectileRect+" _  -  _ "+touchLocation+" _  -  _ "+targetRect);
```

and this:

```
System.err.print(": This is intersect function from App :");
```

change to:

```
System.out.println(": This is intersect function from App :");
```

and this too:

```
System.out.printf("Got touch ", location);
```

change to:

```
System.out.println("Got touch " + location);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on the constructor :

```
this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
```